# Why do some powerpoint presentations have icons that reflect the presentation and some do not

Tags: icons, powerpoint

I am noticing that some icons of powerpoint have the following standard icon:

[image]

However, I also noticed that some presentations have icons that are an image of the first slide.  Why is that, and what do I need to do in order to add an icon image to my presentation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which format (.ppt; .pptx; .pptm; ...) your PowerPoint presentation has.

Comment: You are right.  It seems .ppt will display the first slide, but .pptx will not.  Thanks.

Comment: pptx WILL show the first slide. File > Info Expand Properties to show advanced properties and select SUMMARY. See at the bottom left ...